# Jekyll [Liquid], вывести 5 популярных тегов в коллекции

Tags: jekyll, liquid

Привет. У меня есть уже рабочий код, который выводит все теги в постах коллекции и считает их количество во всех постах.

Вот код:

```
{% assign tags =  site.blog | map: 'tags' | uniq %}
{% assign postInTagCount = 0 %}
<div class="blog-tags__tags-wrapper">
{% for tag in tags %}
    <a href="/blog/tags/#{'#'}{{ tag | downcase }}">
        <div class="tags_wrapper__tag">
            {{ tag }}
            {% for post in site.blog %}
                {% if post.tags contains tag %}
                    {% capture postInTagCount %}{{ postInTagCount | plus:1 }}{% endcapture %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            {% if postInTagCount <> 0 %} [{{ postInTagCount }}]{% endif %}
            {% capture postInTagCount %}0{% endcapture %}
        </div>
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

Как это выглядит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но хотелось бы вывести 5 самых популярных тегов, которые встречаются в постах выбранной коллекции.

У меня есть пример: https://www.codeofclimber.ru/tags/
Но я не уверен, используется ли Jekyll на этом сайте или нет. На Гитхабе в репозиториях автора я не нашел его сайта.

Прошу вашей помощи. Спасибо.